# Phonegap: Force screen orientation portrait/landscape

Tags: android, ios, cordova, screen-orientation

I'm using Phonegap Desktop/CLI to test my app. I'd like to force the screen orientation to be portrait.

I've added this line to my config.xml:
`<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />`

Then I run "phonegap serve". This works neither from Android or iOS.

The app screen listens to the orientation of the phone, turning from portrait to landscape as you rotate it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is unsupported with "phonegap serve". I had to build the app package (apk/android ipa/ios) and install it to my device to get it to work.

I used build.phonegap.com but I guess you can use the SDK's aswell.

Answer (score 0):

With this plugin you can force orientation

https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Comment: Yes, but will that work with "phonegap serve"?
I tried the plugin but never got any error nor success.

Comment: I am using it in cordova, so I don't know. Just try and post the results ;)

Comment: But the plugin is not needed if you use the line:
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
in the config.xml. So why use a plugin?

Comment: With the plugin you can have some screens in portrait, others in landscape and others that rotate in all directions, or make it change only for some devices. Anyway, it won't work with phonegap serve

Comment: Agreed. I'd use the plugin for something like a game. For example (no the best one), title screen in portrait and gamescreen in landscape.